# Import text file(with structure text format) into mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, mysql-workbench

When search about loading text file to mysql workbench, most of the question/answer related to csv.
what if I have a text file like this format:

```
Name="Mary"
Age=18
Address="123 Wall st."
Name="Peter"
Age=23
Address="123 Sesame st."
```

Eventually I would like to have

```
Name Age Address 
Mary 18  123 Wall st.
Joe  23  456 Sesame st.
```

Which function will be useful in mysql workbench for this data format?

Thank you!!

Comment: When you say `MySQL Workbench` do you mean you want to import a text file into a MySQL Database Table? WorkBench is just a tool (Not A Database)

Comment: You may have to write a program to load this, do you have access to a language?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "importing data into MySQL Workbench" you actually mean "using MySQL Workbench to import data into MySQL". MySQL workbench can import two types of data, JSON and CSV. Both have a fixed structure, which is required to allow mapping of strings to table columns. A freeform text file does not qualify here.

However, your second form of data comes pretty close to CSV. You would have to add a field separator yet, to separate fields from each other. Usually a comma is used here (hence the name CSV = comma separated values).

If you can add the separator then it's easy to import that using MySQL Workbench. Use the table data import wizard for that task:

[image]